# Run-time error '1004' Unable to set the NumberFormat property of Range Class

Tags: excel, vba

I installed a very simple command button to timestamp a selected cell. The command button works completely fine until I protect the sheet, then it throws the error mentioned in the title. I have already checked that the cells' format is not selected to 'locked'.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ts As Date

With Selection

.Value = Now

.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Even if the cell is not locked, you'll get a RTE 1004 if you don't allow for formatting of cells when you protect the sheet. Protecting the sheet with `UserOnlyInterface:= True` might be what you're looking for. See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Protection.aspx) for more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## AllowFormattingCells

You have to allow Formatting of cells.

[image]

or in VBA

```
ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFormattingCells:=True
```